How to match keywords as standalone words in Flex without capturing substrings?
I'm writing a flex lexer to recognize specific keywords only when they appear as standalone words (not as part of larger words). For example, if I'm looking for the keyword "in", it should match "in" but not when "in" appears within sins or inline.
Here's the rule I'm currently using:
(?i:if|else|while|class|fi|in|inherits|isvoid|let|loop|pool|then|case|esac|new|of|not) {
    printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);
}

This rule matches in even when it appears within other words like "sins". I tried adding word boundaries by using (^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_]) before and ([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$) after each keyword, as follows:
(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])(?i:if|else|while|class|fi|in|inherits|isvoid|let|loop|pool|then|case|esac|new|of|not)([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$) {
    printf("Keyword: %s\n", yytext);
}

However, this approach doesn't produce any output at all, and I'm unsure why.
I tried using (^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_]) before and ([^a-zA-Z0-9_]|$) after each keyword to simulate word boundaries in flex, expecting this would match keywords only as standalone words. However, this didn’t work; the rule produced no output, and I’m not sure why. My goal is for in to match as a separate word but not within words like sins.

Do you not have a rule for identifiers/names that would match "sins"?

Anyway, I can not reproduce your problem. Your modified rule does produce output for me. It's probably not a good idea because it includes the surrounding characters as part of the match, but it does match in surrounded by non-alphanumeric characters. It does not match at the beginning of a line or at the end of the file though because ^ and $ don't work inside groups.
